# Recieving Unique SMS Replies from Mobile Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms, twilio

Currently i have a database of users who i want to be able to send messages through SMS, so they can go to anyone, but also be able to receive replies back, either through SMS or Email. The problem I'm having is trying to figure out a way to be able to receive SMS from mobile users, through a service such as Twilio, and being able to somehow identify what users those messages should go to, without the use of thousands of different Twilio numbers. As far as i can think of there does not seem to be a way to have the SMS message have a identifier unless you ask the mobile user to input one (which would not be optimal).

I have also tried to do this process through the phone carrier's SMS gateways (EG. 10DigitNumber@tmomail.net) but some carriers seem to send it to the mobile users as a short code rather than an email address, which would not be able to receive replies back.

Any ideas, whether using services like Twilio or not, on this issue would be helpful!

Comment: that almost seems impossible because sms carriers use the phone number and Email uses the `@someemailaddress.com or net etc... do you have an example of the code you're working with.. I have sent messages to both my phones from email using individuals phone number plus carrier etc I just checked and was able to send an email to myself from my cell phone by just typing in the phone number in the `To` section but this may not work with all carriers

Comment: Ya i don't know if this is possible or if it is how complicated it might be. I have tried to do the email option but when i send an SMS to a phone number to certain carriers, specifically T-Mobile, the From field, on the phone, is a short code, rather than the email used by the user on my end. Therefore they mobile user wouldn't be able to respond back.